# how to create custom theme in magento2

Tags: magento2.1.5

I want to create magento theme and inherit the default functionality can any one tell me verified view how to create it.I used many tutorial but not for good

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Create your theme folder at `app/frontend/design/Vnedor-Name/Theme-Name`

add below file theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>New theme name</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

create a file `registration.php` and add below code to it

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/<Vendor name>/<theme name>',
    __DIR__
);
```

add file at etc/view.xml in your custom theme copy it from

```
vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\etc\view.xml
```

Run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

after run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`